# Please read scenario below and help me to solve it

Tags: asp.net, database

I have asp.net web page which populates grid view. One of column is **Status** which can have (Scheduled, InProgress, Failed, OnHold, Completed) these values and another column with link in each row to edit that particular entry. Editing is only allowed for statuses **Failed, OnHold, Completed**  not for **Scheduled, InProgress** on click of entry which has status **Scheduled or InProgress** a pop up appears saying you cannot edit.

Now, click on link and start editing data, at same time another person with same access as mine also tries to edit same data(i.e. clicks on same link) and makes Status to **Scheduled** and clicks submit. The data is saved in database. Before I complete editing.

Now status for that entry is Scheduled and according to requirement it cannot be edited, but I'm able to edit data and save it database.

It should not happen. How to achieve this please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the function or RowUpdating Event of the grid, you should run a SQL statement checking if the status of the row currently being updated is valid for saving (per your requirements).

If it's not, then display an error that it's been updated by someone else to a status different from the one fetched by the 2nd user trying to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Column in your database like "IsEdited" and whenever a record is being inserted first run a query to retrieve the value of "IsEdited" then use If-Else statement to check. If its value is True then don't run the Insert query and display error message and if its value is False then run the Insert query with data for all other columns and also a value (True) for "IsEdited" column.

If you could provide a code it would be easy to explain.